# Optimizing query vs decreasing modelling quality

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, domain-driven-design, data-modeling

I have to present the teams where the user belongs to and the membership information.
It is a many-to-many relation, so I have a `team_user` containing the membership information, like `role_type`, `invited_at`.
And I got a `team` table containing the information about the team itself like the `name` and `description`.

Now I got two ways of querying this via the repository:

```
const user = UserRepository.get(1);
const teams = UserRepository.getTeams(user.id);
const memberships = UserRepository.getTeamMemberships(user.id);

// do something with the data
```

As you can see, to be able to get the teams for a user, I have to *join* the `team_user` table… BUT when only querying the membership information, I have to *join* the `team_user` table as well.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to optimize this? Or isn’t the optimization worth the decrease of quality (?) on the modelling side?

Comment: search for CQRS

Comment: Other than the term repository there is nothing else in your question to relate it to Domain Driven Design

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid querying your domain model.  Your repository should only ever return a full aggregate.  For queries you can use a Command/Query Responsibility Segregation approach where you have a read model or, if applicable, a more primitive type.  I tend to use an `ISomeQuery` interface for the corresponding `ISomeRepository` interface but you could name these using whatever is appropriate:

```
public class UserQuery : IUserQuery
{
    public Query.Membership FindTeamMembership(int userId)
    {
        // here we'll access the data base directly 
        // using as raw a format as possible
    }
}
```

I also currently like to namespace the read models in a `Query` namespace to avoid conflicts with any similarly named domain classes.